# Excel - XLOOKUP with Multiple Results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that contains counties, zip codes, and recording fee. Some zip codes contain more than one county.

For example Zip Code 1314 contains the following counties -- Cortland and Onondaga. I am trying to have excel display both of those once the zip code has been entered and their corresponding fee.

I have attached two images, one is Expected outcome, the other is what I currently have.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet -- https://file.io/4ifrOghDn7ss

**Expected Result:**
[image: Expected Result]

**Current Result:**
[image: Current Result]

Comment: If you have access to the new excel formulas you can use `FILTER` to retrieve all associated rows with your input.

Comment: @urdearboy -- I do have access to the new excel, would you be able to show an example of that?

Comment: Can you upload a sample table as well as an example of the intput/desired output. I'm not going to open a workbook from stranger online on my work computer (stranger danger ;P)

Comment: @urdearboy -- no worries, understandable, I uploaded it to Google Drive -- https://docs.google.com/file/d/1sJBN06RghBM16FrpoJDKQA3pUiNMDtWM/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel

Comment: I have not used `XLOOKUP` yet but I believe you can only output a single match similar to `VLOOKUP`. `VLOOKUP` defaults to find the **first** matched value and the same is true for `XLOOKUP` however it does give you the option to change the order it searches for (i.e. look bottom up rather top down). Since this criteria exists, I assume you can still only output a single matched value. As a result, you are better off using `FILTER`

Comment: Same thing - just post pictures, tables directly to your post. Most people (including myself) will not follow any links off of this site. Either way, I posted a solution that should be sufficient example for you to recreate on whatever your setup is

Comment: How would I go about using FILTER across different sheets?

Comment: Same way you would with any formula. Just highlight the ranges on the appropriate sheets. `FILTER` works across sheets just fine

Comment: using **FILTER** function in a structured reference table will lead to the `#SPILL!` error. I would have used **PowerQuery** for this case but if you just want an instant result then displaying the outcome in a plain worksheet is good enough using the **FILTER** function as suggested by undearboy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your lookup value was in A19, Put this formula in B19:

```
=FILTER(
        FILTER(ZipCode!A2:H53963,ZipCode!A2:A53963='County Lookup by Zipcode'!A19),
        {FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE}
       )
```

The outer filter controls the columns that are displayed.  You may need to change the `TRUE`|`FALSE` values to control which columns are displayed or not.

Two things, this is not the column order you want, so you will have to change the order on Zip Code tab.  Also the cells on your spreadsheet are formatted as text, so be sure to change the formating of the input cell to be general or a number.

[image: Example of FILTER Formula]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `FILTER` function to return all values associated with a input. See a sample input table (*table on top*) along with a output table (*bottom*) where the only input is cell `A9`.

With this set up, just enter the formula on cell `B9` which will import the desired range

```
=FILTER(B2:E4,A2:A4=A9,"")
```

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the link, I uploaded the spreadsheet to Google Drive, https://docs.google.com/file/d/1sJBN06RghBM16FrpoJDKQA3pUiNMDtWM/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel